# Create log in for every user using threads so can create a secret file for that user, where he can put content

Tags: java, multithreading, spawn

```
public static class MyThread extends Thread {

    public void run(){

        String username; // Username of person
        String password; // Password of person
        String m;
        String n;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in

        System.out.println (" Please enter a username:");
        m = reader.nextLine(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
        System.out.println ("You entered username as:" + m);

        System.out.println (" Please enter password:");
        n = reader.nextLine(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
        System.out.println ("You entered password:" + n);

    }
}

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Thread myThread = new MyThread();
    myThread.start();
}
}
```

- Basically, what I need to do is ask user for a username,
- For every user, a separate thread should be spawned.
- Then check if any secret file for that user exists.
- create that file if not
- user can enter any info there
- set password for that
- encrypt file
- so now next time user enters username, he should be asked to enter password.
- then file should open
- he can do anything there

Please help me out in this, I am very new in this.

Comment: You're going in the right direction. Take each of your requirements one at a time. The next thing you might want to look into is support for multiple users. You can do this with a HashMap. If the username is in the map (e.g. map.getKey(username) then the user already exists).

Comment: @Mark, by using HashMap ,i can have multiple users login. What more concept should i have.

Comment: Does all this need to happen over one iteration (i.e. hitting RUN once) of your program? Or are you expected to quit the program and persist the data to the file system?

Comment: No, not in one iteration. But when everytime a new user wants to Log In